# How to get date and time from Date() object?

Tags: javascript

When I have a JavaScript `Date()` object and I use `console.log()` then on the console appears this:

```
Date 2015-12-16T12:00:00.000Z
```

But I need this information in this format:

```
2015-12-16 12:00
```

How to easily do this with string operations? So without using `getFullYear()`, `getDate()`.....

Comment: Why can't you use the inbuilt JavaScript functions? Otherwise simple string handling or regular expressions.

Comment: Why to use string string handling when you have predefined functions ?

Comment: because a lot of coding... I have to also deal with leading zeroes

Comment: @user, I rolled back your latest edit. Please remain civil here. Thank you.

Comment: okay, so another question. how to extract the string from the object in the same format? I need almost the same string which was printed on console... how to have it?

Answer (score 3):

If you can use Momentjs library

```js
$(function() {
  var datestring = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
  $("#result").append(datestring);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"><div>
```

for more examples you cant take a look : http://momentjs.com/docs/

**edit** : Note the slight difference:

- <kbd>h</kbd> - 24 hour time
- <kbd>H</kbd> - 12 hour time used with <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: If it is unclear, you can wrap your existing date inside a moment : **var day = new Date(2015, 12, 16); var dayWrapper = moment(day);**, and call format on it.

Answer (score 2):

this is my way:

```
var myDate = new Date();
var myYear = myDate.getFullYear();
var myMonth = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
if (myMonth < 10) {
    myMonth = "0" + myMonth;
}
var myDay = myDate.getDate();
if (myDay < 10) {
    myDay = "0" + myDay;
}
var myHour = myDate.getHours();
if (myHour < 10) {
    myHour = "0" + myHour;
}
var myMinute = myDate.getMinutes();
if (myMinute < 10) {
    myMinute = "0" + myMinute;
}
var retDate = (myYear + "-" + myMonth + "-" + myDay +" "+myHour+":"+myMinute);


console.log(retDate);
```

Comment: This doesn't pad with leading zeros where necessary.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Where in the question, you find that padding is a concern?(*Although its not a hard stuff to deal with*)

Comment: Well, if the time happens to be 12:00 as per the question, your answer would give 12:0

Comment: @JamesThorpe:- As I said that is not a big stuff to deal with, the answer is not wrong in my opinion! :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi Given the fact that this question is being asked in the first place, the answers probably need to be complete...

Comment: @JamesThorpe you're right,I just edited my answer

Comment: Now you need to pad the month too, and quite honestly I'd expect the hour to be padded in such a format.

Comment: @JamesThorpe:- That is fine. It is now understood! +1

Comment: @JamesThorpe Many thanks~

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

```js
$(function() {
  var myDate = new Date();
console.log(myDate.format("yyyy-mm-dd h:MM"));
$("#date").html(myDate.format("yyyy-mm-dd h:MM"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js"></script>
<div id="date"><div>
```